# Does it constitute murder if the attempted murder fails but the victim dies anyway as a side effect of the attacker's actions?

Tags: united-states, california, murder, utah, manslaughter

For example, suppose an attacker is chasing a victim with a knife and the intention to kill. While running away, the victim falls, hitting their head, and dies.

Assuming there is clear evidence for the the attacker's intentions and how the victim died, can the attacker be charged with or convicted of murder?

I could see them being charged with murder because their actions led to the person's death. But I could also see the charges being limited to attempted murder since the attacker didn't directly cause the victim to fall. Or maybe they would be charged with both attempted murder and manslaughter?

If it varies by state, I will limit this to whether this would constitute murder in Utah or California.

Comment: Welcome to [Law.SE]!  Criminal law is for the most part determined by the individual states in the US, so the answer to your question may vary by jurisdiction.  Is there any particular state you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question

Comment: Sing along, to the tune of "That's amore":  "When you chase them with a knife, and it costs them their life, that's a murder.  When intent was to kill, and they pay their final bill, that's a murder.  If they'd still be alive, had you not shown your knife, that's a murder.  If you caused mortal fear, and their soul's departed here, that's....a... mur...der!!"

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Is there any state where this *wouldn't* be a murder?  I know there's some subtle differences among the various states in the US, but I feel like this case would be pretty unambiguous wherever you are...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman:  I had the "felony murder" concept in the back of my head, where you can effectively be charged with premeditated murder if someone dies in the commission of another crime, even if you didn't intend to kill them.  But in the given scenario you *did* have intent, and so upon further reflection I expect it would be straight-up murder in most jurisdictions.

Comment: I suppose in most states chasing after someone with a knife in your hand and the intention to kill is a felony. And in many states, death as a consequence of a felony is some kind of murder.

Comment: Wait! Your goal was to kill them, and with that in mind, you do something to them, and it makes them die. How is that a "fail?" Was it maybe a problem that they died in the wrong place? at the wrong time? Did it fail on aesthetic grounds? Did it fail to be a sufficiently dire warning to other people who can't seem to keep their noses out of your business?

Comment: @Solomon Slow ok yeah that's a good point. From the attacker's perspective, they succeeded. So "failed" is the wrong word. I guess what I meant was, is there an argument that the attacker didn't actually kill the victim since the victim died by falling rather than being stabbed. And based on answers below, it looks like as long as the running and falling was a result of being attacked, then the the attacker is considered to have killed the victim

Comment: And since falling often happens when you're scared and running, and since running is a natural reaction to being chased by a knife, most people would consider the falling to be a consequence of being attacked. But I imagine if instead of falling, the victim was struck by lightning, then that probably wouldn't be considered murder, since knife chasing can't cause lightning strikes

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, even if this wasn't explicitly murder in a given jurisdiction it would still be felony murder because attempted murder (or even mugging if you successfully convinced a jury that you didn't actually intend to kill the person) is a felony and the person died during the commission of that felony

Comment: @Kostas I'm honestly offended by that. My wife and I were watching Monk where murder happens in lots of odd ways, and there was an episode where a victim was being chased, and my wife wondered whether falling and dying while being chased would count as murder. I thought that was an interesting legal question, so I asked it. I asked it broadly, but the comments suggested I pick a particular state since criminal law varies across states. So I picked Utah because I live there and I'm curious about the law where I live, and I picked California because Monk is set in San Francisco

Comment: I was curious what prompted you to consider this question. At first I was thinking of how Halloween's coming up and some folks like to dress up as murder clowns and startle people in public spaces (i.e. not a haunted house).

Comment: @MaxWilliams I sang that to my wife and had her in a fit of laughter!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[california](/questions/tagged/california)

#### You intended to kill them, you killed them, that's murder

California Penal Code Section 187(a):

> Murder is the unlawful killing of a human being, or a fetus, with malice aforethought.

California Penal Code Section 188(a)(1):

> Malice is express when there is manifested a deliberate intention to unlawfully take away the life of a fellow creature.

---

If this weren't the case, one could nitpick the cause of death almost endlessly.  For instance, what if you stabbed them nearly to death, they were almost saved by a surgeon, but then they died of an infection that they acquired in the hospital?  The law's solution is simple: if you not only killed them, but you also intended to kill them before doing so, that's murder.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129783/discussion-on-answer-by-ryan-m-does-it-constitute-murder-if-the-attempted-murder).

Answer (score 18):

### That’s murder

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

*Crimes Act* 1900 [s18](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1900-040#sec.18):

> Murder shall be taken to have been committed where the act of the accused, or thing by him or her omitted to be done, causing the death charged, was done or omitted with reckless indifference to human life, or with intent to kill or inflict grievous bodily harm upon some person, or done in an attempt to commit, or during or immediately after the commission, by the accused, or some accomplice with him or her, of a crime punishable by imprisonment for life or for 25 years.

The act of chasing the victim with intent to kill caused the death. QED.

Comment: I'm not seeing the explicit connection here. The act of chasing the victim "caused" the death in a roundabout way, but the immediate act that killed the victim was the victim failing to walk in a straight line. Certainly, I can see there existing plenty of case law making that connection, but I can also readily see it being considered an incidental death, reducing the crime from murder to manslaughter or whatever. Most of the time, chasing people, even with a knife, doesn't cause death, so the act performed (chasing) didn't have the intent to kill and isn't inherently "reckless indifference".

Comment: In short, the law you've quoted says what we already knew: murder means killing with intent. The question is whether an accidental death caused by an intentional act that failed to kill is still considered murder. And you'd need to dig a little deeper to properly answer that.

Comment: @Michaels "the act performed (chasing) didn't have the intent to kill". This is highly problematic reasoning. Intent is never found in the *act*, it is found in the defendant's state of mind. In a prosecution these elements are always proven separately. So, first we prove that the knife chasing caused the death. Then, as a totally separate exercise, we prove that the defendant intended to kill. We do not have have prove that the defendant intended to kill by causing the victim to trip and hit their head.

Comment: @JBentley: If I plot to assassinate Bob, then run a red light on my way to Bob's house and accidentally hit and kill Bob with my car, it's unlikely anyone would consider that murder. The intent was completely irrelevant to the act. If I stab someone which results in them eventually bleeding out, the intent was directly relevant. In our case, the only act done with intent is chasing. The victim wasn't actually stabbed, so the intent isn't directly relevant to the death. The knife chasing caused the death. But it didn't do so intentionally.

Comment: In short, no, we don't typically prove cause of death and intent as completely independent elements of a crime. Because they aren't.

Comment: @michael My point is that the defendant doesn't have to intend that that exact action, and only that action, will cause the death. It is sufficient that he does some action X, the purpose of him doing X is to kill, and as a result of him doing X, the person dies. For example, if I thrust the sharp end of the knife at you intending to kill, but I miss and instead the blunt end hits you on the head and you die, I'm not going to avoid a murder charge because I didn't intend to kill you with the blunt end. It is enough that as I thrust the knife, I had it in my mind that I wanted you to die.

Comment: @JBentley: Right, but chasing the person wasn't ever intended to kill. Just like driving through the intersection. But it's closer to the action intended to kill than running a red light. Hence why it's a trickier case.

Comment: @MichaelS You're assuming that the defendant must intend that *specific action* (chasing) to be the thing that kills, but that isn't how it works. It is enough that he does the act (chasing with a knife) and the *purpose* of that act is to kill the victim. Your example of the intersection is different because the *purpose* of you driving through the red light isn't to kill Bob, it's to get to the other side of the intersection. Although the actus reus and mens rea are separate, they still must coincide.

Comment: @JBentley: Purpose and intent are the same thing. In both cases, the purpose of the act is to get to the victim to kill them, not to kill them. The distinction is simply proximity of accident to expected outcome. In the OP's scenario, chasing is expected to immediately lead to an opportunity to stab the victim. In mine, driving through the intersection is expected to get closer to the victim but not provide an immediate chance to kill them. There's also the issue of chasing being a form of assault, which exacerbates the legal ramifications compared to consequences from running a red light.

Comment: @MichaelS I don't see why your case wouldn't be murder. In your example, you were already in a state of mind or shown to be attempting to murder Bob. The jury would probably conclude that you finding Bob at the red light was just a convenient outcome for you (even if it wasn't part of your original plot), allowing you to carry out your intention while making it look like an accident. The only way I would see out of this would be to show that you weren't actually intending to kill Bob at all (not at a red light, and not anywhere), which would make it not-murder.

Comment: @MichaelS I take your point, but in practice that reasoning doesn't work. For example I can extend your logic to say that as I thrust the knife, my intention isn't to kill, it is to get the sharp end of the knife closer to you. Therefore when the blunt end kills you as I make the sharp end travel towards you I have not comitted murder because my act only intends to kill at the exact moment the sharp end pierces your skin. In reality, we don't break down intention into such small fragments. It is sufficient that as you chase the victim with the knife, you have an *immediate* intention to kill.

Comment: @MichaelS If it helps to convince you, this isn't just theoretical. For example Smith and Hogan's Criminal law (the leading criminal law text in E&W) 14th ed at page 108 states: "A long line of cases has established that D will be held to have caused death or injury by so frightening V that V has jumped from a window or a car or behaved in some other manner dangerous to himself. If D's unlawful conduct has prompted the response from V, D will remain liable if V's reaction was within the range of responses which might be expected from a victim in his situation".

Comment: @JBentley Yet if I chase someone with murderous intent, and they trip and fall into a police cruiser, and it turns out that they are a wanted felon who gets the death penalty, I don't think anyone would consider me a murderer. Clearly the line must be drawn somewhere.

Comment: @fax Yes. It is known as breaking the chain of causation or alternatively a novus actus interveniens (a new intervening act). Something that severs the link from the action and the result. See my 3rd comment on [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/72814/3066). However it is well established that things like injury while escaping do *not* break the chain.

Answer (score 18):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

### You're describing a murder

In English Law, the act of running from an attacker would be entirely within the realms of 'causation' (e.g. the attack caused them to escape) and is explicitly called out in case law as one of the things that an attacker would expect their victim to do in self-defence, hence remaining part of the attacker's responsibility.

Per the [CPS (Crown Prosecution Service) guidance on Homicide](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/homicide-murder-and-manslaughter#_Toc3812578);

> To break the "chain of causation" an intervening act must be such that
> it becomes the sole cause of the victim's death so as to relieve the
> defendant of liability - see R v Wallace (Berlinah) [2018] EWCA Crim
> 690; R v Kennedy (Simon) [2008] Crim. L.R. 222. Examples of
> intervening acts are:
> ...
> An act of the victim if not within the range of response which might be anticipated from a victim in his situation: [R v Roberts (1972) 56 Cr App R 95](https://www.lawteacher.net/cases/r-v-roberts.php) and [R v Williams Davis 1992 CLR 198](https://www.lawteacher.net/cases/r-v-williams-and-davies.php).

In both the cases cited above, the victim of a violent assault attempted to flee and were ***injured during their attempt to escape***. The aggressor was deemed to be accountable as this was a *predictable chain of causation*.

Comment: Ive added some more info on English law in my answer too

Comment: As I understand, the causation aspect of it is why Self Defense is an Affirmative Defense? (i.e. the potential victim has a Duty to Retreat (At least in U.S. law, generally, ignoring Stand Your Ground and Castle Doctrine), and if the attacker made someone retreat to an area they could not retreat, the fleer isn't at fault for attacking with intent to harm in same degree of violence?

Comment: @Alexanderthe1st - Yes. The attacker is also responsible for 1) An escalation of violence that occurs as a result of the individual defending themselves, 2) Harm that occurs to the victim as a result of medical treatment, even where the harm is caused by medical negligence 3) Injury to the individual even if the individual has a prior condition that makes them prone to injury.

Comment: I assume this is for England _and Wales_, since they are very closely aligned in such matters. DO you know if it's different for Scotland/Northern Island, by any chance?

Comment: @SamOT - Pretty much identical as far as I'm aware. Not to be confused with Culpable Homicide (which is basically a fancy version of manslaughter)

Comment: I was told by a surgeon who I asked as a professional, that basically any operation has a risk of death. That risk may be very small, but it is always there. So if you stab someone badly enough that an operation is needed, and they die, you should have thought about that before stabbing them. It's murder, even if the death was negligence by the surgeon.

Comment: On the other hand, I read about a victim being transported in an ambulance, the ambulance got into a car crash, and the victim of the crime died in the crash. And _that_ was unrelated enough that the perpetrator wasn't convicted for murder.

Comment: @gnasher729 - A link would be useful. I'd be intrigued how the defence managed to argue that the victim being in the ambulance was unrelated.

Comment: The victim being in the ambulance was clearly related, but the ambulance getting into a car crash wasn’t.

Comment: @gnasher729 - Yes, but he wouldn't have been in the ambulance except for the assault

Answer (score 8):

This will depend upon the legality of your actions so far, and how closely they are related to the death.

For instance, if you were chasing that person with the intent to kidnap them, torture and then kill them, it’s going to be murder because you are committing a crime and they die because of that.

If instead, you called and invited them to your house with the intent to do the same thing, and they get hit by a bus on the way, you haven’t yet committed an illegal act and you are free and clear (albeit disappointed that you didn’t get to torture them first).

So, the key question is going to be did they die as a result of a crime you committed, and how closely that crime was related to their death.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe could be construed as felony murder in it is a death that happened during the committing of a felony. You were in the process of assaulting the victim and then he slipped and hit his head against a rock and died from that. In some states felony murder carries the death penalty like Nevada for instance. Intentions are pretty clear, you don't chase a person with a knife if you intend to do no harm.

Answer (score 4):

Also in English Law, the rule is, if you intended serious harm to a person, and a person dies because of it, that's murder.  This definition means that:

1. You didnt need to intend their death. Its enough to prove you intended to do them serious harm, and they died as a result of what you did. That's murder.
2. It doesnt have to be the same person. If you intended serious harm to person A, but because of your actions a different person B died, thats murder as well.

So if you punch someone hard enough, and they fall and die, the question will be whether you knew or should have known it was likely to do "serious harm", or would do it,  or whether you intended "serious harm". (Sometimes the courts emphasise the criterion by describing it as "really serious harm" when talking to a jury.)

Also if you mean to kill, or even "seriously harm", one person, and a different person dies - a bystander, or wrong victim - dies, thats murder too.

In both cases, the "chain of causation" in Richard's answer is used to decide if the death was, or was not, a result of **your** actions, or resulted legally from some other cause.

Comment: These are all correct for English law but not really relevant to the OP's scenario because the hypothetical defendant *did* intend death (so it's not necessary to discuss intention to harm) and there was no transferred malice to a different person B. The answer to the OP's question mainly involves consideration of the law on factual causation and reaction of the victim. Legal causation and intention are part of premise of the question.

Comment: Sure. A bit of extra background can help, since the underlying question is clearly more about exploring what constitutes murder anyway, notwithstanding it picks one clear example to.test the water.....

Answer (score 3):

### Also applies to injuries and in tort law. See the *[eggshell skull rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggshell_skull)*.

Which says that if you intend to do a harm, "the unexpected frailty of the injured person is not a valid defense to the seriousness of any injury caused to them."

So even if you manage to escape the murder charge, O.J. Simpson style, the victim's family gets another bite at the apple, in civil court. And there, they get to use all the evidence from the criminal trial, *but the standard of proof is only "more likely than not" i.e. 51% likely*.  Since all the evidence has already been vetted by the criminal court, it is "shooting fish in a barrel" for the civil plaintiffs.

So you will end up bankrupt and a pauper for the rest of your life, and even worse, you will have to live in Florida if you want to accumulate wealth via home equity, it being the only state that protects unlimited equity in a homestead.  That is why OJ lives there.

"Rest of your life" because bankruptcy doesn't clear liabilities from intentional crimes.

Think about that.  You get in a quarrel with someone and push them against the wall and yell at them, and they have a record of being extremely prudent about COVID precautions so it 51% more likely than not their fatal case came from you... boom, wrongful death.  You could not have imagined they were not vaccinated, nor that you even had COVID.

Comment: "You will have to live in Florida" Or move to a country that doesn't respect US civil judgments.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica "Live in Florida"? NO WAY!! Doesn't the US have a prohibition against cruel and unusual punishment?

Answer (score 1):

In the USA, if you commit a felony, and someone dies as a result, that’s murder.

It doesn’t matter whether you intended to kill them (although you said they did). But it must happen as a foreseeable result. Foreseeable is for example two armed bank robbers committing a felony by robbing a bank, and police shooting one of them, the other is guilty of murder. Foreseeable is if you stab someone with a knife, they are taken to hospital, and they die because of a stupid and negligent act in the hospital. Not foreseeable is if you stab someone, they are taken to hospital in an ambulance, and that ambulance gets hit by a truck and your victim killed. It would be foreseeable if the victim tries to run away, runs into the street without looking or falls over their own feet and gets killed.

It would *not* be murder if the death was *not* an intended or unintended result of your felony of attempted murder. Still attempted murder, of course.